# x/text/message/pipeline placeholders and MERGE

Tags: go, language-translation

I'm trying to use the pipeline package to emulate gotext but reading from templates. There are a few things that I don't understand. My steps are

1. Read all templates and build up `pipeline.State.Extracted`
2. `Import` my current translations into `pipeline.State.Translations`
3. `Merge` (1) & (2) into `pipeline.State.Messages`
4. Refresh the existing JSON files with `Export`
5. `Generate catalog.go`

I've noticed a few things that have meant having to change the `Import` & `Merge` procedures

In the Import there is some explicit code which stops the files previously generated from being imported. The code is here:

```
// TODO: Should we skip files that match output files?
if fmt.Sprintf(i.outPattern, tag) == file {
    continue
}
```

In the Merge, the Placeholders imported from translations aren't merged into messages

Can someone explain the reason for these two design decisions?